# Wordpress Domain name in IIS

Tags: wordpress, redirect, iis, url-rewriting, url-routing

I am new to working with IIS. I have tried researching the issue but I can't find any useful information. 
So I have two websites (mock names).

One is: 
`www.websiteA.com` which is located at `/directory1/websiteA`

The other is:
`www.websiteB.com` which is located at `/directory1/websiteB`

They have the same IP, but separate 'A' records.
I set up bindings for both websites to be on IIS to a certain URL.

So `www.websiteA.com` and `www.websiteB.com` are both bound to their own URLs accordingly using the 'Bindings' option in IIS.

**Website 1**, `(www.websiteA.com)` works fine and it also masks the URL name. It is a **simple HTML site**.

**Website 2**, `(www.websiteB.com)` also is completely functional, but it does not mask the URL name. It acts more like a pointer for some reason, writing out the server and directory inside the url bar. It is a **Wordpress** installation.

I am not sure if the way my url is displayed is happening through IIS or Wordpress. The website works fine but it's not masking the directory properly. Is there something this newbie can do? Do I need to create a URL rewrite somehow?

Help appreciated!
Thank you.

**Additional Note:** There is no https set up yet, they are both plain http. I am using Windows Server 2019. Both have their own web.config files.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. The issue was not IIS but Wordpress. Solution:
Go to your Wordpress Admin page and go to the 'general' section and change the site URL and wordpress URL. If these are greyed out (like in my case), go into the wp-config.php file in the root folder and update it manually via code there.

Comment: This is one of the most typical issues of WordPress, so glad that you found it out yourself.